# How to import main folder from another folder

Tags: go

app/main.go

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
)
var varInMain string

func exm() {
    varInMain = "Hello, playground"

    fmt.Println(varInMain)
}
```

app/folder/call.go

```
package folder

import (
    "fmt"
    Main "../" -> ERR// or "app" -> ERR
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println(Main.varInMain)
}
```

I can not call main.go variable or func. from folder/call.go.
How can i do it? //And thats must be local package

Comment: You cannot import a main package. A goapp can only have a single main package. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am sorry my mistake. edited

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share vars across packages then create a separate package where you declare exported variables by the first character in caps.

app/mypack/vars.go

```
package mypack

var MyVar string
```

then import in main and other packages like
    package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    mypack "app/mypack" 
)

func main(){
    mypack.MyVar = "Hello, playground"
}
```

same way import in app/folder/call.go and use

Comment: Thank you that is worked

Answer (score 2):

Main means that this package uses everything in your project(if not just remove it from your project and everything will be ok). And so you cannot import main because of cycle import. So you should create separate package and use it in main and in other packages if you want.